# k8s: prod and non prod env's: best practices handling software & cluster upgrades at the same time

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Due to constraints and limitations, contracts and otherwise, I am in a situation where I only have the ability to run microservices in two different clusters: one for prod, and the other non-prod.

The problem i envisage with this arrangement is that there will be inevitable situations whereby users are testing new software features (different images) in the non prod environment, when the cluster itself is in a newer version than what's in production.

What are the best practices of managing cluster variation in addition to variations between environmeents when it comes to new images? How do you go about versioning the cluster & the software at the same time to be able to accurately do testing if the clusters are not the same version? Should someone opt to get the cluster versions the same before new development can be done on the cluster?

How do other people handle this situation? I am used to running in three different env's

Comment: When you say cluster versions, do you mean kubernetes versions like v1.24, v1.25, v1.26..? In general we won’t update or upgrade kubernetes control planes too frequently unless and until we need to patch some vulnerabilities or kubernetes has deprecated them. 

Kubernetes labels help you to specify the environment and the image versions etc., using these labels in your deployment you can specify the environment and the image you want to use in that environment, for more information go through this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)

Comment: I am in a situation with GKE where the main core cluster components on the control plane are abstracted away, managed entirely by google, and I'm left only to make considerations on release channels /or manual node upgrades keeping in line with GKE skew policy, where the nodes must be at least two minor versions below master. 

Updates happen enough for me to be leery of having env differences (and yes, k8s versions) on nodes, while also potentially having different application versions running also. Two sets of variables are shifting simultaneously, or at least, can be, and I want to limit

Comment: There are two ways to create a GKE cluster. If you have chosen the autopilot mode you can't select the GKE versions and they will be automatically taken care by GKE however, if you chose manual mode you can select the GKE version while creating the cluster and regarding the skew policy you got it wrong nodes and node pools can be two versions below the control plane but it's not mandatory to be two versions below, go through this [GKE versioning and support](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning#:~:text=Google%20provides%20a,skew%20policy) for more information.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what my question is. Yes, this is a standard/manual deployment mode. I am aware about the skew policy and what it means, the question is about how to handle the difference in node version between environments in addition to differences on a software level (as in, image differences, deployment versioning from k8s objects within the clusters of each env) Does that make sense?

Comment: Since you are saying that you are not having control over node updates I gave the above explanation. Now coming to the second part of handling node image differences you can separate your configuration from the application by using configmaps and secrets and use labels for specifying your application to run on a specific node(where it mandatory to maintain same base). Since you are having two environments you can create a simple CICD pipeline which will deploy applications to production once it's successfully tested in non-prod.

Comment: You can perform rolling updates in this case follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/updating-apps) for more information.